# Is the usage of 'nor' correct, in this example, with no noun that follows: Not all people who go to the park are happy nor have hopes of feeling happy

Tags: american-english, neither-nor

Can 'nor' be used in the following way (without a noun that follows and comma that proceeds):

> 1. Not all people who go to the park are happy **nor have** hopes of feeling better.

Or is this the only correct way in such a sentence:

> 2. Not all people who go to the park are happy, **nor do they** have hopes of feeling better.

Comment: As is often the case, difficulties arise because a difficult way of expressing a concept has been chosen. I would simplify the whole process here by saying _Not everyone who goes to the park is either happy or hopes to feel better_.

Comment: @JasonBassford Why do you think the question does not deserve an answer?  Is it too easy, perhaps?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I only indicated that it's a duplicate of another question. I believe that the question itself should certainly be answered.